# modal form with two parameters

Tags: jquery

I need a jquery form dialog that calls a function with two parameters after it accepts the form. One parameter is from the form and another one from where the dialog is initialized/opened.
how should I do this without using global variables?

edit:

```
$("#something").click( function(){
  var global_var=param2;  
  $('#dialog').dialog('open'); 
}


$('#dialog').dialog({modal: true,  
                     autoOpen: false,  
                     buttons: {'Cancel': function(){}  
                               'Accept': function(){ callback($('#widget').val(),global_var);}  
                              }
                    });



<div id="#dialog">
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="widget" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: so I click a cell in a table, get some id of the row ancestor (which isn't illustrated here, let's call it param2) then I open up a dialog from where the user inputs a field. The field and the param2 need to be sent as parameters to a function. using a global variable isn't very elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try create input hidden with your param2:

```
$("#something").click( function(){
  $('#dialog').find('#param2').val(param2);  
  $('#dialog').dialog('open'); 
}


$('#dialog').dialog({
   modal: true,  
   autoOpen: false,  
   buttons: {
       'Cancel': function() { }  
       'Accept': function() { 
            callback($('#widget').val(), $('#param2').val());
       }  
   }
});



<div id="#dialog">
  <input type="hidden" id="param2" value="" />
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="widget" />
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure:

```
(function(){
   // anything in here is local to this closure
   var foo = 0; // local
   bar = 1; // global
   $("#elementName").dialog(<options here>, 
   onBeforeClose: function () { <do something here>});
}())
```

Comment: can bar be sent in the dialog parameters?